# Can one macro show columns on first run then hide the columns on the second run?

Tags: excel, vba

Can I assign one button to two macros in Excel?

Each macro only to be run when the button is pressed.

For example:

- First time button is pressed it will show columns.
- Second time button is pressed it will hide columns.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. One button can only trigger one procedure.

But you can write a procedure that can toggle the visibility of your columns.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ToggleColumns()
    Dim ColumnsToToggle As Range  ' The range you want to toggle
    Set ColumnsToToggle = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    
    ColumnsToToggle.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not ColumnsToToggle.EntireColumn.Hidden
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if this were possible.

You might opt for something like:

```
Sub Toggle
  Some_Range.Hidden = not Some_Range.Hidden
End sub
```

Comment: It's not possible ;) Because a `Range` object has no `.Visible` property (but a `Hidden` property). And it needs to be an `EntireColumn` (or `EntireRow`) of a range as a `Range` cannot be hidden. See my answer.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: my answer is meant as a first step in the right direction, using some pseudo-code. Nevertheless, I've replaced the non-existing `Visible` property by the `Hidden` one.